# Aggregation on facebook can not be created?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I Am having developer account on Facebook. I have Implement Facebook graph API aggregation in one of the app, and the same method Of implementation I am trying to use and create aggregation in another app. But options to create aggregation is not available in new app edit section. 
How to do this??

 Have attached two images for reference.

 In first image it has aggregation option where as in second one it doesn't have it.

Thanking you for your help

[image: aggregation implemented]

[image: aggregation not implemented]

Comment: I have same issue Ive added types,collections and story to both apps . I created a App ages ago and it has Aggregations but a App I created 6 weeks ago dose not have option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen because you might have not defined any Open Graph Object or Action types. Define the same or create a story and then you would get the option to aggregate these stories.